# Bootstrap 3 variable modal width displays double scrollbars

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've followed this tutorial:

http://scottpdawson.com/development/creating-a-variable-width-modal-dialog-using-bootstrap-3/

in order to make the modal window width variable. Everything is working except two things:
1). Once the window is resized to small size the double "y" scrollbars appears.

2). Also when the window is resized the modal window is pulled to left corner while it should be centered.

This is strange because the demo code from tutorial works perfectly, but in my case it doesn't...

Any help?

The live example is here: http://tedxmru.com/ted-mob/

pressing the **Concept** button opens the wide modal with those problems

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    html {
        overflow-y:hidden !important;
    }
}
```

however you wont be able to scroll the main page after doing this.

**Similar questions:**

[Bootstrap 3 modal creates scrollbar when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829332/bootstrap-3-modal-creates-scrollbar-when-opened)

[How to hide the body scroll bar when showing modal dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292783/how-to-hide-the-body-scroll-bar-when-showing-modal-dialog)

---

Alternatively, I would like to recommend this plugin that makes modal windows in a snap - [Remodal](http://jquery-plugins.net/remodal-flat-and-responsive-jquery-modal-plugin)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. I've tried it in that way, but no luck:   `.modal-wide .modal-body {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: auto;
}`

Comment: are you sure that u applied it to you <html> tag itself? I tried it in chrome developer windows and it worded fine.

Comment: In such way, as you say the default y-scrollbar is turned off and page doesn't scroll at all. Also the problematic modal window still wasn't fixed